# Confine yourself to the present in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I know that Meditations was originally written in Greek, but I'm curious to know how you would write "Confine yourself to the present" in Latin? Thanks.

Comment: Note that _Confine yourself to the present_ is one translator's version (Long, 1862). Farquharson, 1944, renders it _Define the time which is present_, which would have an utterly different Latin translation from Long's version.

Answer (score 7):

In the original Greek, your quote is:

> περίγραψον τὸ ἐνεστὼς τοῦ χρόνου. (*Meditations* 7.29)

This literally means: "Circumscribe the present time." (See meaning III.2 of the [LSJ entry for ἐνίστημι](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3De)ni%2Fsthmi).)

While it would be simple enough to imagine a Latin equivalent, there is actually already a famous translation by [Wilhelm Xylander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Xylander) (or, in German, Holtzman) in the 16th century.

A facsimile of this Latin edition is available [here](https://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/~db/0001/bsb00015212/images/). The [relevant passage](https://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/0001/bsb00015212/images/index.html?id=00015212&groesser=&fip=xsxdsydqrsewqyztseayaxsewq&no=21&seite=124) is translated as follows:

> **Circumscribe instans tempus.**